# Dom Exception 18 open database - angularjs and cordova

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

How to initialize sqlite db when using only angular.js and cordova without ionic?
Below is the sequence of existing app initialization.

```
$(function() {
  new init();
});

var init = function() {
// Check platform - web browser, iOS, android

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iOS|iPad|iPhone|Android)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
} else {

    initializeApp('browser');
}

// Device Ready event for cordova
function onDeviceReady() {

    initializeApp('device');
}

// Bootstrapping Angular manually.
function initializeApp(platform) {  

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {

         angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

    });
}

}



// Angular Module and configurations
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.router', 'myApp.constants', 'myApp.helper','myApp.directives', 'myApp.utils', 'myApp.services','ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'myApp.filter','chart.js']);
```

Comment: where you write code for sqlite open db?

Comment: That is what my question is...when i write it in .run method or any controller its giving dome exception error.

Comment: yes you can use .run method

Comment: Thanks Paresh, but i am not using Ionic, its purely angular.js, bootstrap and  cordova based application.

Comment: Then else syntax work for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use .run method for creating db. here i attach my code for sqlite for web and cordova also so you can sqlite db in browser when you use `ionic serve`

```
var db = null;
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova','timer','ionic-datepicker','ionic-timepicker'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite,$ionicPopup) 
{
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() 
    {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard)
        {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar)
        {
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }

        if(window.cordova)
        {
            // App syntax
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("myapp.db");
        }
        else 
        {
            // Ionic serve syntax
            db = window.openDatabase("myapp.db", "1.0", "My app", -1);
        }

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users ( UserId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, CloudId INTEGER, Email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, IsEmailVerified TEXT DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL, UserLanguage TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT English, IsAutoSyncOn BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, DateUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateAdded TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateDeleted TIMESTAMP)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Photos( PhotoId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, Source TEXT 'Standard' NOT NULL, Category TEXT, ThumbnailURL TEXT NOT NULL, PhotoURL TEXT NOT NULL, DateAdded TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateDeleted TIMESTAMP)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Devices( DeviceId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, UserId INTEGER NOT NULL, DbVersion INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, DateLastLogin TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NbrTimesSinceLastUpgradeNag INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, DateLastSync TIMESTAMP, DateSyncServiceExpires TIMESTAMP, DateLastReviewRequest TIMESTAMPDEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NbrLogins INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, DeviceName TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT iPhone, DateUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateAdded TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Events( EventId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, CloudId INTEGER,UserId INTEGER NOT NULL, EventName TEXT NOT NULL, DateEvent TIMESTAMP, Category TEXT, ReminderIntervalNbr TEXT, ReminderIntervalUnits TEXT, RepeatInterval TEXT 'No Repeat' NOT NULL, PhotoId INTEGER, DateUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateAdded TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DateDeleted TIMESTAMP)");
    });
})
```